# How to find a parameter name of a Simulink block?

Tags: parameters, simulink

Consider following example. I have a [*PID Controller*](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/pidcontroller.html) block in Simulink. I want to change its *Upper saturation limit* using [`set_param`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/set_param.html):

> `set_param('model/PID Controller','Parametername','Parametervalue')`

How can I know the parameter name (`'Parametername'`) corresponding to the *PID Controller*'s *Upper saturation limit* parameter? I know that there is a [list](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/block-specific-parameters.html) of parameters of common blocks, but the *PID Controller* is not included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find block parameter names in the *Model explorer*.

In this example, it was `UpperSaturationLimit`.